# XMLHttpRequest cannot load [url] Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

Tags: javascript, ajax, wcf-rest

This is my ajax code:

```
    var param = "<ClientOrder xmlns='http://www.eysnap.com/mPlayer'>";
    param += "<ClientId>CRF-1</ClientId>";
    param += "<UserKey>598zxc8ddl45a3cvScuk</UserKey>" ;
    param += "<PassKey>p1re254l3jd83os00cpk</PassKey>";
    param += "<OrderId>123132323435</OrderId>";
    param += "</ClientOrder>";

    $.ajax({

        url: URL, 
        data: param, 
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "text/xml",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(result){
            alert('success');
            $("#div1").html(result);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert('error');
            $("#div1").html(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

The service I'm calling is restful. The crazy thing is that when I call a GET service, it returns the data correctly, but with POST service it gives this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load [url]. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The servica provider decides the method, not the caller. If it is provided as `get`, then you have to comply. It may not be REST compliant, but that's the way it is :-)

Comment: `HTTP Error 405 Method not allowed` which means they do not allow POST requests.

Comment: no actually, thats another service that allows GET. This service is specifically made for POST. I need to send a POST request.

Comment: @YvoCilon: it can't be possible. I'm already calling this service with POST in a C# code. Now when I try to do this with JQuery, it doesn't work!

Comment: CORS issues ... if the site doesn't allow CORS then the site doesn't allow CORS ... server -> server will work, browser -> server will require CORS enabled on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it was namespace issue.

```
<ClientOrder xmlns='http://www.eysnap.com/mPlayer'>
```

I changed the namespace to correct one.